# SSE изменения в бд

Tags: php, сокет

пытаюсь узнать изменения(добавление нового значения) в бд, но не получается, подскажите как надо:

```
    $ch = $this->getChange();

    if($ch >= $ch+1) {
        echo "data: 1" . "\r\n"
    } else echo 'data: 0' . "\r\n";

     function getChange(){
        $link = connect();
        $q = query($link, "SELECT * FROM table");
        close($link);

        return $q->num_rows;
    }
```

проблема в том, что  я не понимаю, как отследить изменения, так как этот файл с выше указанным кодом, постоянно обновляется(висит), и не получается получить старое значение

Comment: Вы пытаетесь узнать число строк в таблице, а не изменения в БД. Что там висит - вообще не понятно.

Comment: мне нужно узнать не добавилось ли новое значение

Comment: Таблица с полем, в котором записано время добавления спасет вас.

Comment: каким образом??

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE creationTime > {$lastCheckTime} как-то так.

Comment: проблема в том, что $lastCheckTime каждый раз перезаписывается... и не возможно хранить страрое значение, чтобы его потом сравнивать

Comment: У вас же БД есть, в ней и храните...

Comment: я не совсем понимаю эту технологию, но буду весьма благодарен, если вы меня вытерпите... файл который весит на стороне сервера ждет пока бд не изменится(то есть не добавиться новое значение). я не понимаю, как нужно сохранять старое значение, чтобы его потом сравнивать... как я понимаю SSE не long polling, и каждый раз с клиента отправляется новый запрос.. и переменные сбрасываются.. вы предлагаете создать отдельную таблице для работы с SSE?

Comment: @maschine: А что такое SSE? Знаю polling, long polling (оба костыля объеденены таким понятием, как [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)) и нативный WebSocket протокол.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вам действительно нужен SSE? Если вы контролируете скрипты, которые вносят изменения в базу - SSE должны рассылать они - тогда в этом будет смысл.

В вашем случае получается классический polling, но в какой-то сложной реализации.

При таком варианте вам необходимо или хранить в базе данных id последней позиции (SELECT max(id) FROM table LIMIT 1) как предлагали выше - или хранить это max(id) на клиенте - и спрашивать сервер на предмет текущего max(id) - обновлять по необходимости данные клиента.